# Put an exception to RewriteRule in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, exception, mod-rewrite

Here is my .htaccess file content

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule  ^$ main/    [L]
    RewriteRule  (.*) main/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here is my directory structure

```
www
 |- ads
 |- main
 |- .htaccess
```

With this configuration all website ex.(http://www.sitename.com) incoming links are meant to go to index.html on sub directory ***main***.
Now I want to make an exception ex.(http://www.sitename.com/ads), to redirect to the sub directory ***ads***.
How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: The .htaccess is redirecting everything to main, so if sitename.com/ads is requested it will look for ads in main folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 solutions:

Add a rule for "ads" before others

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule  ^ads$ ads/ [L]
    RewriteRule  ^$ main/    [L]
    RewriteRule  (.*) main/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Or don't rewrite for existing directories

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule  ^$ main/    [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule  (.*) main/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```